# How to make Slider Responsive in Html and Css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <style>
           #slider {
               height: 350px;
               width: 70%;
               margin: auto;
               overflow: hidden;
               background: #CCC;
           }
           .slide {
               height: 350px;
               float: left;
               text-align: center;
               border: 1PX SOLID #000;
               line-height: 8em;
               font-size: 40px;
           }
     </style>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"/>
     <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              // you can set this, as long as it's not greater than the cv.slides length
              var show = 3;
              var w = $('#slider').width() / show;
              var l = $('.slide').length;
              $('.slide').width(w);
              $('#slide-container').width(w * l)

              function slider() {
                  $('.slide:first-child').animate({
                      marginLeft: -w
                  }, 'slow', function () {
                       $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).css({marginLeft: 0});
                  });
              }
              var timer = setInterval(slider, 2000);

              $('#slider').hover(function() {
                  clearInterval(timer);
              },function() {
                  timer = setInterval(slider, 2000);
              });
          });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body background="../background2.png">
  <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-top:60px; color:#fff; fb f            font-size:60px">Slider</h1>
  <div id="slider">
     <div id="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 6</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the full code for making the slider.

This is a linear type of slider which can be use for to display the products or all about its categories.

How to make this Slider Responsive?

Comment: I've formatted your code to make it easier to read. For future questions, please format your code, and make sure you trim it down to a [mcve]. Please also use paragraphs and proper punctuation in the test of your question. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Update the css .

Take out the absolute height value from the **slide class** and add `width: 100%`
The reason you want to take out the height is so you do not have a fixed height that becomes a problem when resizing or on smaller devices.

In the slider ID

```
#slider {

               width: 100%;//add this

           }
```

This will have all your slides lined up vertically and responsive.

Here's what you should have for what it seem you are trying to do.

```
   #slider {
       width: 100%;
       margin: auto;
       overflow: hidden;
       background: #CCC;
   }
   .slide {
     width: 100%:
       height: 350px;
       float: left;
       text-align: center;
       border: 1PX SOLID #000;
       line-height: 8em;
       font-size: 40px;
   }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you're declaring width and max width, max width needs to be in px not a %. Isn't what you posted telling it to have 100% width but max width of only 70%

Comment: Updated. Yes, you are correct. In the case, he should take out the max-width since it is not serving any purpose. The container seem to be a determinant for the w variable in the slider js function.